# Why a row count being added automatically in the first column in react-data-table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-data-table-component

[image: React table in UI]

I am using [react data-table component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-data-table-component). It was working fine but suddenly the row count is showing up automatically in the first column as shown in the link above. I made no changes to the code. What could be the possible reason?

```js
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import {
  connect
} from 'react-redux';
import columns from './CustomsCellsToDataTables';

const WorkInProgress = (props) => {
  return (
      <UploadDataTable
        noHeader
        columns={columns}
        data={props.batchUpload.data}
        dense
        noDataComponent={<EmptyGridResult />}
      />
  );
};
WorkInProgress.defaultProps = {
  batchUpload: []
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WorkInProgress);
```

I am using styled-components. I tried to hide the auto-generated row count like:

```
.rdt_TableBody {
        .kOmeBk, .esymFC {
             display: none;
          }
        }
```

It worked for me for a few days but class got changed to a new class and the row count is again visible in the UI.
Every time I am adding the class and setting display: none but after someday a new class is replacing the older class. Any suggestions? 
What could be the reason for a class getting replaced with a new one?
Does the styled component has something to do with it?

Comment: Write your code - the way you are rendering the table in your component. Mere image is not sufficient to help

Comment: @user2063635 added code.